# Unwanted loading of relations in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hello,

I have problem with EF Core feature - It automatically binds related entities together when the entities are somewhere independently attached to current dbCotnext.

Let's assume following two entities:

```cs
    public class Seller {
        public Guid Id {get;set;}
        public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
    }

    public class Product {
        public Guid Id {get;set;}
        public Guid SellerId {get;set;}
        public Seller Seller {get;set;}
    }
```

And some code in the controller (just for imagination):

```cs
var seller = DbContext.Sellers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == someId);
var products = DbContext.Products.All(t => t.SellerId == someId);
return StatusCode(200, products);
```

The returned JSON will be like

```cs
[
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "sellerId": "5678",
        "seller": {
            "id" : "5678",
            "products": ["(muted reference loop exception from json converter here.)"]
        }
    }
]
```

But I don't want the Seller to be included in each Product. If I did, I'd call *Products.Include(...)* for that or something else.
I don't want to crawl through entities and null the navigation properties. 
I don't want to hide it with [JsonIgnore] because *sometimes* the relation must be included.
I also don't want to manually detach every entity all the time when this happens.

The question is, is there any way to disable or work around this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Try `public List<Product> Products {get;set;}` change to nullable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't/shouldn't. You need separate dto class(es).

Newtonsoft.Json is responsible for object serialization, it decides which properties must [not] be serialized. You can control it's behavior only using it's attributes. You can't control it from EF :)

And as soon as you wish sometimes to include property and sometimes not - you need two different classes (each with correct attributes). Everything other is a hack. DTO, Automapper and all this stuff - you are welcome.

BTW, having different class(es) for external API and internal data storage allows you to easily change one without breaking other (in future).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change model class and using **nullable** type.

```
 public class Product {
        public Guid Id {get;set;}
        public Guid SellerId {get;set;}
        public Seller? Seller {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Question is about `Product.Seller`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this configuration on Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.

    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(a => a.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

    // other code
}
```

Comment: Question is not about loop, it about `Seller` property.

Comment: Seller is a navigation property inside of Product, you can disabled reference loop to serialize the result without a circular reference, I'm agree with you about DTO but not always all developers use DTO, the first version of question it was about to avoid the behavior of circular reference and with this piece of code you can handle it

Comment: `Project.Seller` is not a circular reference (`Project.Seller.Projects` is).

Comment: since `Seller` and `Product` both reference each other, they are circular references. This is a good and appropriate answer.